# implementing a decision tree with more than 2 children at each node

Tags: matlab, decision-tree

I am implementing a decision tree in MATLAB

As attributes, I have 13 nominal matrices that i gathered them together in a big matrix. I mean in first column of this big matrix there is my first attribute as a vector and so on.

My 12 features have the values of 0 and 1, but the last one has 251 different numbers, which means 251 children!

How can i define nodes for this tree? Before seeing the values of 13th feature I did like this :

```
tree = struct('value', 'null', 'left', 'null', 'right', 'null');    
leaf = struct('value', 'null', 'left', 'null', 'right', 'null');
```

but it won't handle my problem now,

Comment: do you want to automatically create a classicfication tree? could you post the data?

Comment: I have an algorithm which at first I should implement it and then use for train and test.
I don't know how to post my data, please guide me and I will post it

Comment: we wont need all of it just enough to create a tree. please add 3 of the features for about 10 points (so a 4x10) matrix of the data to your question so we could try something

Comment: my problem is creating a node with more than 2 children, not the number of features. Do you know it ??
All the implemented trees in the internet are binary.

Comment: to the extend of my knowledge matlab trees are all binary. But you can break every non binary decision down to multiple binaries and i think that is the only option you have

Comment: Are you sure about this? they are all binary!
Features with two types of value are binary, but one attribute of mine has more than two types. This is the confusing part of my algorithm.

Comment: well yes  for example if the attribute can be 1,2 or 3 the first binary decision is | <1,5 or >1,5 | and the >1,5 goes to | <2,5 or >2,5| so a attribute with n different values can be branched out with n-1 binary decions. this wont get pretty if you have a lot of values in a attribute but it works

Comment: thanks a lot,
really thank you.